# Swift 2 - AFNetwork request caching issue

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift2, afnetworking

I am using below AFNetworking code for networking request

```
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
        manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()

        var parameters = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        parameters["key"] = Constants.urlKey


        manager.POST(Constants.categoryProductsUrl,
           parameters: parameters,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            let productAdapter = ProductAdapter()
            productAdapter.mapResponseOnModel(responseObject, error:"", pageLoaded:page, categoryLoaded:categoryId, callback:callback)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,error: NSError!) in
            print("afnetworking GET producst   - Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            let productAdapter = ProductAdapter()
            productAdapter.mapResponseOnModel("", error:Constants.ERROR_SOME_THING_WENT_WRONG, pageLoaded:page, categoryLoaded:categoryId, callback:callback)
    })
```

but response is not being cached, even though I have mentioned cache policy as following:

```
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
```

server headers are following
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem emerged here recently: 
[set-cache-time-afnetworking-swift-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312142/set-cache-time-afnetworking-swift-2)

However, it is in Objective-C. You can embed code from obj-c but if you don't feel like going back into obj-c why not use another new stuff : 
[AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Cache Control in AlamoFire:
[alamofire-nsurlcache-is-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785693/alamofire-nsurlcache-is-not-working)

Comment: Alamofire also not working when server not provides caching headers